# Difference between AlertDialog.builder's obj.create() vs obj.show() vs obj.create().show()

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Is there any difference between .create() and .show() methods of AlertDialog's builder class? Like when we create an alert dialog using:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new 
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
builder.setMessage("");
builder.setPositiveButton(....)
builder.setNegativeButton(....)
```

What is recommended pratice to use and why?

```
builder.create() //I have seen this creates and displays the dialog
```

OR

```
builder.show() //this also displays the dialog
```

OR

```
builder.create().show() //well same thing
```

I have read the documentation. But was unable to make any sense from it. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`obj.create()-For create Dialog`

`obj.show()-For show Dialog`   <- without it you cant show dialog if you created.

**and**

`obj.create().show()-create and show Dialog i mean both same as above two in one statement.`

Comment: so if I just call .create() it won't pop up the alert dialog?

Comment: @KKD right! Create will not `show` your Dialog. In Fact the Builders `show()` calls `create()` first....

Comment: The documentation says ".create() allows the user to do any extra processing before displaying the dialog". just curious what sort of extra processing ?

Comment: Thanks guys. I got my answer.

Comment: .create() and .show() is not equivalent to .create().show(). Method .create() returns an AlertDialog. In the first case you are calling .create() and .show() of AlertDialog.Builder and in the second case you are calling .create() of AlertDialog.Builder followed by .show() of AlertDialog.

Comment: would you mind giving us answer @drulabs, we are a little curious here.

Answer (score 0):

[builder.show()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder#show()) returns an AlertDialog object and displays it immediately. As stated in the documentation, calling this method is functionally identical to:

```
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show();
```

[builder.create()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder#create()) returns an AlertDialog object with the arguments supplied to the builder, without showing it. This might be useful if you want to create and store the AlertDialog object for additional processing, after which `dialog.show()` may be called.